# Reemplazar valores perdidos (nulos) en una columna especifica de un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, dataframe

Buen día, necesito reemplazar los valores perdidos de una columna específica de mi DataFrame, ya que como lo estoy haciendo actualmente me reemplaza valores perdidos en todas las columnas del dataframe:

```
df_isnull = df.fillna(0)
df_isnull.head()
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.fillna` permite pasar un diccionario (también una Serie u otro DataFrame) en el que la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor el valor sustituto de los valores `NaN` para esa columna. Aquellas columnas que no existan en el diccionario/Serie/DataFrame simplemente no son rellenadas. Por lo tanto,  pasa un diccionario con solo la columna objetivo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (1, np.nan, 3, np.nan),
                   "b": (5, np.nan, np.nan, 7)})

df_isnull = df.fillna({'a': 0})
```

> ```
> >>> df_isnull
>
>      a    b
> 0  1.0  5.0
> 1  0.0  NaN
> 2  3.0  NaN
> 3  0.0  7.0
> ```

Recuerda que puedes hacer la operación sobre el mismo DataFrame, sin realizar una copia:

```
df.fillna({'a': 0}, inplace=True)
```

Si la razón de querer substituir los valores en una sola columna es que quieres que en otras columnas se sustituyan los valores nulos por otros valores, usar un diccionario es la solución más simple:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (1, np.nan, 3, np.nan),
                   "b": (5, np.nan, np.nan, 7)})

df_isnull = df.fillna({'a': 0, 'b': np.inf})
```

> ```
> >>> df_isnull
>
>      a    b
> 0  1.0  5.0
> 1  0.0  inf
> 2  3.0  inf
> 3  0.0  7.0
> ```